# Xamarin forms is not implementing Binding

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I am new to Xamarin forms and I am trying to create a simple app with some inputs and save them in the database. However the binding doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure what is wrong.

Here is the model:

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SiteVisits.Models
{
    [Table("Well")]
    public class Well
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LatitudeCoordinates { get; set; }
        public string LongitudeCoordinates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using MvvmHelpers;
using MvvmHelpers.Commands;
using SiteVisits.Data;
using SiteVisits.Models;
using SiteVisits.Services;
using SiteVisits.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SiteVisits.ViewModels
{
    public class WellViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public AsyncCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public WellViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Well Information";           
            SaveCommand = new AsyncCommand(Save);
            var wellService = DependencyService.Get<IWellDataStore>();
        }
     
        string latitudeCoordinates, longitudeCoordinates;
        public string LatitudeCoordinates
        {
            get => latitudeCoordinates;
            set
            {
                latitudeCoordinates = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LatitudeCoordinates");
            }
        }
        public string LongitudeCoordinates
        {
            get => longitudeCoordinates;
            set
            {
                longitudeCoordinates = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LongitudeCoordinates");
            }
        }

        private async Task Save()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(latitudeCoordinates) ||
               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(longitudeCoordinates))
            {
                return;
            }

            await WellDataStore.AddWell(latitudeCoordinates, longitudeCoordinates);

            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
    }
}
```

The service:

```
using SiteVisits.Models;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace SiteVisits.Services
{
    public class WellDataStore
    {
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
        static async Task Init()
        {
            if (db != null)
                return;
            // Get an absolute path to the database file
            var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyData.db");

            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Well>();

        }
        public static async Task AddWell(string latitudeCoordinates, string longitudeCoordinates)
        {
            await Init();
            var well = new Well()
            {
                LatitudeCoordinates = latitudeCoordinates,
                LongitudeCoordinates = longitudeCoordinates
            };
            await db.InsertAsync(well);
        }
        public async Task<Well> GetWell(int id)
        {
            await Init();

            var well = await db.Table<Well>()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ID == id);

            return well;
        }

    }
}
```

Interface:

```
using SiteVisits.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SiteVisits.Services
{
    public interface IWellDataStore
    {
        Task AddWell(string latitudeCoordinates, string longitudeCoordinates);
        Task<Well> GetWell(int id);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SiteVisits.ViewModels" x:DataType="viewModel:WellViewModel"
             x:Class="SiteVisits.Views.WellInfo">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:WellViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags = "All">
            <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                
                <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Label Text="Latitude Coordinates:" />
                    <Entry BindingContext="{Binding LatitudeCoordinates}" x:Name="LatitudeCoordinates" FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Label Text="Longitude Coordinates:" />
                    <Entry BindingContext="{Binding LongitudeCoordinates}" x:Name="LongitudeCoordinates" FontSize="Medium"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And xaml.cs:

```
using SiteVisits.Models;
using SiteVisits.Services;
using SiteVisits.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SiteVisits.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class WellInfo : ContentPage
    {
        WellViewModel viewModel;
      
        public WellInfo(WellViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.viewModel = viewModel;
            BindingContext = this.viewModel;
        }

        public WellInfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new WellViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

    }
}
```

The BaseViewModel is of type INotifyPropertyChanged. When I put a breakpoint in the ViewModel in Task Save(), it shows latitudeCoordinates and longitudeCoordinate null even though I have tried to put values in them.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are setting the BindingContext twice, in the constructor and in the XAML.  Remove it from the XAML

Comment: I removed this bit ` <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:WellViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>` and it's still not working.

Comment: are the setters of your bound properties getting called when you update the UI?

Comment: No, only the get gets called but the set never gets through the breakpoint.

Comment: that's pretty weird.  If you want to post the project somewhere I'll take a quick look at it.

Comment: I've tried adding it to github but it won't allow me for some reason. Any idea where else I could post it? Thanks!

Comment: you can just zip it and post it to any file share service

Comment: Should be able to download it from here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldl-yW1n95GPj7gpnGn-ej3ye_wucpnf/view?usp=sharing) . Though there are other files in there, I'm concentrating first on the Well part and then sort the others out as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong

```
<Entry BindingContext="{Binding LatitudeCoordinates}" FontSize="Medium"/>
```

you need to bind the `Text` property

```
<Entry Text="{Binding LatitudeCoordinates}" FontSize="Medium"/>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! Now I can see the values in the setter. But now when it gets to `await WellDataStore.AddWell(LatitudeCoordinates, LongitudeCoordinates);` in the vm I get an error **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'** and in threads it says **System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal()**. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: your VM never initializes `WellDataStore`

Comment: Right.. so I added in the vm `IWellDataStore wellService;` & in the WellViewModel class ` wellService = DependencyService.Get<IWellDataStore>();`  and changed the bit with AddWell into `await wellService.AddWell(latitudeCoordinates, longitudeCoordinates);` and  gives me the same error.

Comment: something is null, you need to figure out what it is.  The most likely culprit is `wellService` - have you checked to verify that it is not null after the call to `DependencyService`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the wellService comes back as null. It is though initialised as `public interface`  so what could be the reason for being null?

Comment: Where are you registering it?  Generally DependencyService is used to access platform specific classes, which does not apply in this case.  Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I was following some tutorials on pluralsight with their sample solutions and then some others from microsoft. So that's how I ended up with what I have. I am very new to Xamarin so a lot of the logic doesn't fully make sense to me yet. I'm not sure I am actually registering it anywhere or where I should. Sorry for being a nightmare.

Comment: if you need more help with this please post a new question.  This issue is really different than the binding problem you originally posted about.  I'd suggest reading the MS docs on using SQLite and following the pattern they use.